# Why is my AWS DMS task with pglogical failing on dropped and renamed tables?

Tags: aws-dms, pglogical

I have an AWS DMS database migration task running Full Load and Replication.  The source is RDS (Aurora PostgreSQL) and I have pglogical configured.

The task ran the initial load just fine, and replication was working until we changed the name of one table in the source database, and dropped another table.  At this point the task started failing.  Here's a subset of the error messages:

```
Matched table found, owner is 'public' name is 'organization_tos_accepts'
Matched table found, owner is 'public' name is 'side_by_side_stripe_responses'
relation cannot be null
Unable to add table 'public.side_by_side_stripe_responses' to replication set...
Failed to process  - ' select case when exists (select * from pglogical.tables where nspname = 'public' and relname = 'side_by_side_stripe_responses'
Error occurred during Get DDL type for 'public.organization_tos_accept'...
Parsing DDL data has failed.
```

[Full error output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SGgQvjBVqfnx9pE_mAB9M8epHIK8Dj-U/view?usp=sharing)

`side_by_side_stripe_responses` is the table that was dropped, and `organization_tos_accept` was renamed to `organization_tos_accepts`

It appears that pglogical is still showing these tables as needing to be replicated, but when DMS tries to get information about them, it fails.

What do I need to do to get the DMS task to run successfully?  I don't need the table-level statements (alter table, drop table, etc.) to replicate - I'm consuming the output with a lambda and only care about record inserts, updates, and deletes.  I'd like for DMS to just ignore these two tables altogether, as they no longer exist.  Note that I have tried modifying the task with selection rules to exclude those two tables, but I still see the same errors.

Terraform for dms task:

```
resource "aws_dms_replication_task" "warehouse-prod-replication-task" {
  migration_type           = "full-load-and-cdc"
  replication_instance_arn = aws_dms_replication_instance.production.replication_instance_arn
  replication_task_id      = "warehouse-prod-replication-task"
  table_mappings           = "{\"rules\":[{\"rule-type\":\"selection\",\"rule-id\":\"1\",\"rule-name\":\"warehouse-prod-replication-task\",\"object-locator\":{\"schema-name\":\"public\",\"table-name\":\"%\"},\"rule-action\":\"include\",\"filters\":[]}]}"
  source_endpoint_arn   
   = aws_dms_endpoint.dms_source_endpoint.endpoint_arn
  target_endpoint_arn   
   = aws_dms_endpoint.dms_target_endpoint.endpoint_arn
  start_replication_task   = "true"

  replication_task_settings = jsonencode(
    {
      Logging = {
        EnableLogging = true
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: I still don't know why this happened, which is why I'm adding this as a comment rather than an answer, but the following steps at least allowed the job to run successfully:
- Modify the dms source endpoint to ignore ddls
- Add an exclusion rule to the dms task for the deleted table
- Increase the replication instance from t3.small to t3.medium